# How to access the orbeon form data id on client-side?

Tags: client-side, orbeon, xforms

In my application, I render my own page and inject the content of Orbeon URL `/orbeon/fr/appname/formname/new?orbeon-embeddable=true` in a `div`.

On save, I need to create a relationship between the `form_data_id` and my entity id. I can capture the click event on the save button but I haven't found the `form_data_id` on the Form DOM or any Orbeon JavaScript object.

Where is the `form_data_id`, or how expose it? Do you have another approach to create a relationship with the `form_data_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to Orbeon's document id, and you can use JavaScript in your own page, then use the following function call.

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue("fr-parameters-instance-document")
```

This will return a string, e.g. "4a1ae3c34a8e14e70c8fc3a02234a847d13896a9".

Comment: Thanks for answer! But with Orbeon 3.9 on Firefox, I get "TypeError: control is null" =(

Comment: Ah, yes, this might be something new with 4.0. Sorry, but I would need to do some research to find how to do this with an "older" version. If your company has Dev Support with Orbeon, you might want to send an enquiry to Orbeon through that channel instead.